# Sub-Domain forward to a URL using Mod_Rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, http-status-code-403

I'm currently using mod_rewrite but would like a specific URL path to use a subdomain name. Would this be possible with `mod_rewrite`?

Currently the URL is like this:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?wiki/index/ -> http://domain.com/forum/wiki
```

How can I get the url to be

```
http://wiki.domain.com/forum/
```

when the wiki directory does not exist? I keep getting a 403 as the directory does not exist and so it's forbidden. I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/wiki/index[R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on mod_rewrite, just put these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/wiki/?$ http://wiki.domain.com/forum/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will redirect `http://domain.com/forum/wiki` to `http://wiki.domain.com/forum/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tip: *you don't need to do a redirect actually*.

Just have **one** vhost that handles both domains.

Just do an internal rewrite, and it will work.

Here's a mix of my own vhost (*that handles `domain.com` and all `*.domain.com`*) and what you'd like (this may not work 100% but hey I give you two hints after this):

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.fr
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/domain/prod/website"

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ErrorLog "/web/logs/domain.error.log"
    CustomLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /web/logs/domain/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 5M" combined

    # your RewriteRules ()
    RewriteEngine On

    # Trace:
    # (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
    RewriteLog "/web/logs/domain.rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    # Your RewriteRules ()
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*) /wiki/index.php?wiki/index$1 [QSA,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)